# Reference ASP .NET Core 5 assemblies from class library

Tags: asp.net-core, migration, .net-5, asp.net5

I'm a little bit lost and confused when migrating from .NET Core 2.2. to .NET 5.
I've developed as class library which was referencing let's say `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions`.

When I create new NET 5 application it implicitly references version 5.0.0 of said assembly (I understand because it uses `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`, but when class library is created the highest version available from Nuget is 2.2.0.

How can I reference 5.0.0 from class library? Should I reference 2.2.0 (it still downloads it though) and hope that 5.0.0 is backwards compatible? What was the intended usage pattern?

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions" Version="???"/>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

**Edit:**
I found out that is should be done with:

`<FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App"/>`

bit this will only work if targetting `net5`, is it possible to reference said assembly from `netstandard2.1`? If `netstandard2.1` can only reference version 2.2.0 is it safe to do it?

Comment: It seems that it is impossible, because there are much difference between .net core2.2 and .net5 library.

Comment: @user1986237 does this mean that, for example, https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Web.AspNetCore/ won't work in .NET 5? (as is it not targeting .NET 5, just .NET Standard 2.0, as is using, among other, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.Abstractions >= 2.1.0)